# Strange Solr spring behaviour

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, spring-data-solr

When I built my query with Spring data, it produce the following query:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/pride_projects/select?q=accession:*PXD*+OR+accession:*PRD*+AND+publication_date:[2012\-12\-31T00\:00\:00.000Z+TO+2012\-12\-31T00\:00\:00.000Z]`

This gives me no results. I have manually change the query in my Solr to:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/pride_projects/select?q=accession:*PXD*+OR+accession:*PRD*+publication_date:[2012\-12\-31T00\:00\:00.000Z+TO+2012\-12\-31T00\:00\:00.000Z]`

Here the output:

`{
     accession: "PXD000002",
     project_title: "The human spermatozoa proteome",
     project_description: "The human spermatozoa proteome was in depth 
     characterized using shotgun iterative GeLC-MS/MS method with peptide 
     exclusion lists.",
     project_sample_protocol: "This LC-MS/MS analysis was repeated twice 
     by digested band using an identified peptide exclusion list, 
     generated by Proteome Discoverer, from the previous LC-MS/MS runs of 
     the same sample.",
     submission_date: "2012-01-02T00:00:00Z",`

Removing the last `AND` and now the query works. I would expect similar behavior with both queries, but not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason the result should be the same when you remove an AND requirement - the default behavior for your setup is probably that all clauses are optional except when you are specific about requiring it (through `AND`).

Since your `publication_date` interval only matches a single millisecond, it doesn't match any documents - so in your last query it's being ignored (and would affect score if a document matched).

```
2012-12-31T00:00:00.000Z TO 2012-12-31T00:00:00.000Z
```

.. the start of your interval is the same as the end of your interval, but since you used `[` and `]` (which means that the value itself is included) you would get a match for a document indexed with exactly that millisecond.

You probably meant to filter for a far wider range.